# Hosting folder structure

Tags: php, laravel, server, path, hosting

I want to move a Laravel app/website from localhost to a live hosting server but I got confused or I'm just plane stupid. After all the searches and documentation that I've found online, about the folder/file structure, everyone seems to have this format:

`/var/www/html;`

I have a hosting plan on one.com and if I look at the advanced settings i see that the File system path is  `/customers/a/6/c/mywebsite.one//httpd.www/` .

Now my question is: How are the folders on my host in relation with the ones from what everyone else has? Where does the /var and /www  begin. I'm scared that I will do something stupid  because I've never had to deal with this kind of stuff before. Sorry in advance if this is a stupid question. A bit of help greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

LE: One thing that I just can't find is that public_html folder that every "ultimate guide" speaks about. ... but I guess I must start reading about Apache HTTPD.

Comment: That all depends on you webhost and how they are configured. It doesn't matter where you put your website files as long as the config is correct.

Comment: I would usually recomand a vps for laravel, but check the web for how to deploy laravel on shared hosting

Comment: Questions about how your hosting is configured are better answered by your host's customer service than StackOverflow. We'd be guessing.

Comment: It does sound like it would be worth your while reading on on how UNIX file systems work in general, and how the DocumentRoot directive in Apache HTTPD works.

Comment: Thank you. That's a start. There is where it got me confused  at that httpd. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I just ssh into my host and after few  cd .. and ls I found out what is going on.
In the file manager in "cPanel" on one.com the folder that you have access to is httpd.www
 aka public_html. But by ssh  I was able to see the whole   `/customers/a/6/c/mywebsite.one//httpd.www/`    so mywebsite.one has 3 subfolders:
httpd.private, httpd.www and tmp

So now I know that I must put my Laravel folder in the httpd.private and the public folder from Laravel in httpd.www, plus doing the correct routing.

Hopefully someone will find this useful.

Have a nice time further.

Thank  you